# How to draw from a csv file with rows as plots and non-numeric columns as x-axis?

Tags: pgfplots

I have a small csv file. Each row in the file corresponds to a result of method and each column a measure about the method for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.csv}
Method, Mx,       My      , Mz 
A,      1,       1.2      , 0.7
B,      2,       0.8      , 0.8
C,      3,       0.9425   , 1.2
D,      4,       0.4794   , 1.1
E,      5,       1.4565   , 1.5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot table [col sep=comma] {mydata.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to draw a plot for each method vs each measure. In other words, I want to draw a plot that its x-axis is the measures, Mx, My, Mz and its y-axis are the values of the measure. I want to draw these plots for every method A, B, C, D and E in the same plot.

I am working a while on this using various questions, but I'm getting nowhere. The above example is clearly not working in this case and I don't know how to change it for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transpose the table with `\pgfplotstabletranspose` from the `pgfplotstable` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.csv}
Method, Mx,       My      , Mz 
A,      1,       1.2      , 0.7
B,      2,       0.8      , 0.8
C,      3,       0.9425   , 1.2
D,      4,       0.4794   , 1.1
E,      5,       1.4565   , 1.5
\end{filecontents*}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{mydata.csv}\Data
\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=Method]\TransposedData\Data

\begin{document}
% if you want to see what the transposed table looks like
%\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\TransposedData}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xtick=data,
  xticklabels from table={\TransposedData}{colnames}
  ]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,5}{
  % note x expr = \coordindex
  \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=#1] {\TransposedData};
  % the following to get the legend
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmpI}{#1-1}
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\tmpI}{Method}\of\Data
  \addlegendentryexpanded{Method \pgfplotsretval}
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```